# Trying to bring access token using approval code, client id, etc

Tags: c#, winforms, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm using C# to implement youtube login in my application and I was wondering why it is keep returning 'bad request' message whenever I request for access token
I've got client id, client secret, redirect uri, etc to access but it keeps returning me bad request.
Please tell me whats wrong with my code

```
            try
            {
                string clientId = "~~~";
                string clientSecret = "~~~";
                string redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
                string tokenEndpoint = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response_type", "token"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret)
        });


                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, content);
```

Comment: please edit your question and include the full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue you can not use urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob as a redirect uri you need to use localhost

second the post body should be in the form of a query string

```
code=[REDACTED]&client_id=[REDACTED]&client_secret=[REDACTED]&redirect_uri=https:\\127.0.0.1&grant_type=authorization_code
```

third why not use the google .net client library?

Comment: Do you mean using google .net client library is using external web program to make user login? if so, since I want user to login throught web in my program, that would not be an option for me.

Comment: I used to get a authcode by getting 
```csharp
url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval/v2")
```
```csharp
if (part.StartsWith("approvalCode=")){
     return part.Split('=')[1];
}
```
But it's not getting url after making a revision so I was wondering if it is correct way to get auth code

Comment: You cant do a login though a web view in your application its going to have to be the system browser installed on the users machine.

Comment: I'm aware of policy so I used chromium and changed user setting if this is what you are worrying
```csharp
settings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 /CefSharp Browser" + Cef.CefSharpVersion;
```

Comment: I wish you luck google is to smart for this you cant hake your useragent